# Upload to Heroku - ProgrammingError: relation does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed my application to Heroku, but I am not able to add any data.
When I tried to open first table with data from model I received this error message:

```
ProgrammingError at /category/category_table
relation "tables_category" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "tables_category"
```

And when I tried to add first data I received this error message:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/tables/category/add/
relation "tables_category" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "tables_category" ("category_name") VALUES ('sho...
```

I went through similar Q/A here, but they do not solve my issue, as I have:

a) deleted all migration files from my local disk, then

b) I run: python3 manage.py makemigrations

c) I run: heroku run python3 manage.py migrate

So all should be up to date and I have this log from Heroku:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, tables
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

So currently do not know what to do.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant in your post. Its not from your local disk you should remove the files, its from the heroku database. If you dont care about what you already have on your database. (heroku dashboard ->resources->Heroku PostGres ->settings->Reset DataBase. And you should be able to redo your migration.

Comment: thanks a lot for help, I deleted Heroku DataBase and applied new migrations and it is working and I can add data. Deployment pretty hard process for me, so once again thanks a lot for help.

Comment: "I have deleted all migration files from my local disk"—don't do this! Migrations are for moving from one known state to another. If you delete your migration files you can easily get into a situation where migrations work on one machine but not on another. Deleting migrations is usually a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't delete migrations

The first step here is very dangerous:

> I have... deleted all migration files from my local disk

It is very likely that the new migrations you generate won't work on your local machine. They will attempt to migrate from an empty database to whatever your current state is, but you (presumably) already have tables and maybe even data in your local database from earlier migrations.

Deleting migrations is almost never the right answer. I know a lot of people recommend it whenever you get into migration trouble, but they are wrong. Throwing away your database might feel safe during early development, but it definitely isn't desirable when you have real data later on.

I strongly suggest that you restore your old migration files, then generate new migrations on top of them.

### Generating and applying migrations

When you run

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

you generate new migration files *on your local machine*. Heroku has no idea that they exist, so running

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

won't do anything.

After cerating migrations on your local machine, apply them *locally* by running `python manage.py migrate` to make sure they do what they're supposed to do. When you're happy with them, commit the files, redeploy to Heroku, and *then* run the migrations on Heroku.